# Вывести список всех плейлистов канала YYY через YouTUBE API

Tags: ajax, youtube-api

Заинтересовался YouTUBE API. Нужно вывести список ВСЕХ, абсолютно всех плейлистов (на самом деле достаточно их id и названия) опред. канала, а затем по опред. `playlistId` вывести уже все видео из плейлиста (опять же достаточно id и названия). При этом `channelId` известен.

Решил использовать

- playlists.list:

  ```
  https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlists?part=snippet&channelId=[ID_Канала]&maxResults=50&key=[API_Token]
  ```
- playlistItems.list:

  ```
  https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet&playlistId=[ID_Канала]&maxResults=50&key=[API_Token]
  ```

Проблема в том, что максимальное кол-во элементов на возвращаемой странице странице - 50, и я не нашел ни как увеличить это количество, ни как сдвинуть начальное значение, чтобы получать записи партиями.

Comment: Вы в ответ не смотрели? Там должны возвращаться `nextPageToken` и `prevPageToken` и их можно использовать в `pageToken`, если не ошибаюсь.

Comment: @Visman Аахах) Я просто не въехал в pageToken)) Спасибо